# Stop a Windows service on re-installation and uninstallation in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, windows-services, inno-setup

I have an installer that starts a service on completion of installation. It stops and deletes the service on uninstallation it stops and deletes the service. After a successful installation of the app if I try to run the installer again it throws an error saying *'Setup has detected that application is already running'*. How can I stop the service before installation happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup reports that, only if you set [`AppMutex` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex).

If you do not want the installer to detect that the application (service) is running, do not set the directive.

If you want to stop the application (service) before the detection, you can do it in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) in installer, and using [`InitializeUninstall`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstall) in uninstaller. *Though note that making changes to user's machine before the user confirms anything, is not the right thing to do.*